# Norton Security Blocking Trojan.Gen.SMH (github.exe)

Tags: windows, virus, github, trojan, norton-security

I've been using GitHub Windows App for several months and now Norton Security is blocking it because it's assuming it's a trojan (Trojan.Gen.SMH to be exact). I removed it from the quarantine but I still want to know why Norton Security would all of a sudden block it. Is anyone else experiencing this problem? Here are some pictures:

[image: Norton Security blocking trojan.gen.smh screenshot 1]

[image: Norton Security blocking trojan.gen.smh screenshot 2]

Comment: "I still want to know why Norton Security would all of a sudden block it." - Its obviously a false positive. it happens, just make an exception so Norton does not scan that folder.

Comment: same thing just happened to me when i got home =/

Answer (score 1):

According to GitHub support Symantec confirmed it was a false positive and has pushed out an update via LiveUpdate to correct this.  If you let Norton quarantine this file you can reinstall by doing the following:

1. Open Explorer
2. Go to the %LocalAppData%\Apps directory
3. Delete the '2.0' folder located there
4. Launch GitHub Desktop again

Answer (score 0):

It is just a false positive, these kinds of false positives happen fairly often with anti-virus. I'd also suggest whitelisting the github folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Symantec had removed the .exe. To fix I went to programs and features and click on github. Then I picked restore to previous state from the options available. This restored the .exe that had been removed.